# How can i validade a button click through an array of inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, forms, validation

I have an array of inputs:

```
<div id="playerZone" *ngFor="let player of team;let i=index">
  <div id="buttonZone">
     <div class="buttonsAdd">
       <mat-form-field appearance="outline" #f="ngForm">
          <mat-label>Summoner Name</mat-label>
          <label>
             <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder" 
                (change)="updatePlayerSumonerName($event,i)">
          </label>
       </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>

<button mat-raised-button routerLink="/waiting" [disabled]="" (click)="placeOnTheList()" hidden="">Waiting Room</button>
```

And a button that i only want to enable if all inputs are filled, and i dont know how to do that.

I need some guidance.

I could create variables that get to true when the input is written, but i know that is a better way of do that

```
updatePlayerSumonerName(name,i){
    console.log(name.target.value);
    this.team[i].summonerName = name.target.value;
  }
```

Comment: @ScottMarcus Looks like angular from the `*ngFor` attribute at the root, etc.

Comment: Give more information on `updatePlayerSumonerName` function. then only one can help

Comment: Yes its Angular

Comment: Post edited for u

Comment: this seems like a `FormArray` use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve ur requirement as below.

Please check this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tpfcfy?file=src/index.html)

in your app.component.ts,

```ts
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  players = [
    'player1',
    'player2',
    'player3',
    'player4'
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
  form = this.fb.group({
    team: new FormArray([])
  });

  ngOnInit() {
    this.addPlayers(this.players);
  }


  get team(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('team') as FormArray;
  }

  onFormSubmit(): void {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.team.length; i++) {
      console.log(this.team.at(i).value);
    }
  }

  addPlayers(players: string[]): void {
    players.forEach(player => {
      this.team.push(new FormControl(player, [Validators.required]));
    });
  }


}
```

and app.component.html,

```ts
<div class="container">
    <br>
    <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit()">
        <div formArrayName="team">
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="commessa" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Team</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let player of team.controls; index as idx">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                <input type="text" [ngClass]="{'error':player.invalid && player.touched}"
                                    [formControlName]="idx" class="form-control" id="commessa">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </ng-container>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```